# Android Structure of Modules for Multiple Projects with Same Functionality

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.2

I have to create 5 Android Application with some common modules. As I have think, I have to create one project with all the optimization and then **copy paste** for other projects but in that scenario we have to change all the resources. All the other things will be same.

As Android Studio is best IDE, Is it providers any functionality to make that type of functionality with easiest way. Something like Common Modules or Libraries.

Any Help, It would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: make a common library and use as a common module :)

Answer (score 0):

create repository in maven central and add your library there,then you can add your library by gradle

here is link for [publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:publishing_artifacts_tutorial) your library to repository